# Maintaing credentials in a stateless RESTful web service between calls

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth, restful-authentication

I'm writing a rest web service which authenticates and authorizes against an LDAP server.  The problem is that calls to the LDAP server are somewhat expensive due to the way everything is configured.  Consequently I am trying to minimize the number of calls I have to make to it.

In a normal stateless design, each call to the rest backend just be authenticated and authorized.  I'm trying to figure if/how I can accomplish this without having to contact the LDAP server each time.

I've been toying with the idea of using a custom token upon initial login and require the client to return the token at each request, but short of encrypting the token or signing it, I can't think of a secure mechanism that would allow me to do this.  But to encrypt a new token at each response, and decrypt at each request will put extra overhead that I would gladly avoid as well.

Caching the LDAP response is a concept as well, but then that opens to a whole bunch of other concerns as well (cache life, clustering, etc).

Is there a mechanism that I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: DO NOT Use OAuth1 it is obsoleted by OAuth 2. You should consider using one of the many OpenID Connect libraries. (Based on OAUth 2.)

Comment: @jwilleke Is there an advantage of using an OAuth2 or OpenID lib versus just creating my own token and encrypting with AES?  Using OpenID seems like overkill given that I do not have an OpenID authentication server in place, etc.

Comment: Openid Connect and OAUTH 2.0 are open and have been tested and abused by many. Your own creation would ne c er be as mature and well tested.